# npm install failed in GitHub Actions

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, github-actions

`npm install` is not able to find the `package.json` file in github actions!

I'm currently creating a github actions file where it would test all `js` files in the `testing-folder` folder, and it looks like this:

```yaml
    test:
        name: Test examples
        timeout-minutes: 30
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        strategy:
          matrix:
            node-version: [ "18" ]
        steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v3
          with:
            fetch-depth: 0
            lfs: true
        - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
          with:
            node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        - name: Install dependencies
          run: |
            sudo apt update
            sudo apt install -y protobuf-compiler libssl-dev
            npm install -g package-json-merge
            node compile_testing.js
        - name: Create files
          working-directory: testing-folder
          run: |
            bash merge-package.sh
            iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8 temp.json > package.json
            cat package.json
            npm install                                     <<< FAIL
        - uses: swatinem/rust-cache@v2
        - name: Run tests
          run: |
            cd testing-folder
            for d in *; do
              if [[ $d == *.js ]]; then
                echo "$d";
                node "$d";
              fi
            done
```

For some context, the `compile-testing.js` file simply moves all the `js` files and `package.json` files from various subdirectories into the testing folder. The `merge-package.sh` script merges all the `package.json` files using a package called `package-json-merge`. This part all works, as I can run this locally and can run `npm install` using the created json file.

But for some reason in github actions, the `npm install` attempts to find the `package.json` in a temp folder, even though my working directory is in `testing-folder`. Below is the output of using `action-tmate` to ssh into the runner:

```bash
    runner@fv-az567-244:~/work/recipes/recipes/testing-folder$ ls
    commands.sh               transformers_package.json  old-package.json  index.js      temp.json
    transformers_index.js  merge-package.sh              package.json      index_package.json
    
    runner@fv-az567-244:~/work/recipes/recipes/testing-folder$ npm install
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
    npm ERR! syscall open
    npm ERR! path /home/runner/.npm/_cacache/tmp/uyJJoq/package.json
    npm ERR! errno -2
    npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/.npm/_cacache/tmp/uyJJoq/package.json'
    npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
    npm ERR! enoent
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2023-07-24T23_12_46_705Z-debug-0.log
```

Does anyone know a workaround or a fix to this? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

`npm root` in the testing folder directory returns this:

```bash
runner@fv-az805-158:~/work/recipes/recipes/testing-folder$ npm root
/home/runner/work/recipes/recipes/testing-folder/node_modules
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer! The issue is caused by a dependency, and when it tries to `npm install`, that dependency tries to run its own `npm install` which has a missing `package.json`. The fix is just by not using that dependency or asking the developers to fix the problem.